# aurora-mysql join results are weird

Tags: sql, mysql

I have 2 tables and when i join them on ID column I get very absurd count. Is it a bug or something wrong from my end?

```
 Env: Aurora MySQL (5.7.12)
 cpu = 8 vcpu
 RAM = 64GB RAM
 Table1: 1555778 Records
 Table2: 1294229 Records
```

Am joining on ID column where table1.ID=table2.ID

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM  table1 t1 JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.ID = t2.ID;

+-------------+
| COUNT(*)    |
+-------------+
| 15172673205 |
+-------------+
```

Thank you,

Comment: have you check for duplicate id in either table?
SELECT ID, COUNT(*) 
FROM table1 
GROUP BY ID 
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;

SELECT ID, COUNT(*) 
FROM table2 
GROUP BY ID 
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;

Comment: Yes there will be some duplicate values . around 100 records

Comment: well, That is the reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments. That is the reason you have that count: duplicates. Try this

```
WITH 
    CTE_Table1 AS (SELECT DISTINCT ID  AS id FROM table1),
    CTE_Table2 AS (SELECT  DISTINCT ID AS id FROM table2)

SELECT 
    count(*) from CTE_Table1  t1 inner join CTE_Table2 t2 on t1.id=t2.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM  table1 as t1 Inner JOIN table2 as t2 ON t1.ID = t2.ID;
```

***If you have duplicate values in ID column it could really generate abnormal count.

Comment: Thank you, am running Inner join and left join to see the behavior . it is taking 60-90 mins to execute. in another environment with more than 6million records i get result in less than 15 seconds. this particular environment am seeing this behavior

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @Horaciux and @kazi-mohammad-ali-nur-romel

Abnormal behavior is due to duplicates as you stated. thank you again.
Here is the query i used and see the results as expected.

```
SELECT count(*) FROM table1 t1 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT NULL FROM table2 t2 WHERE t1.ID = t2.ID);
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|  1339145 |
+----------+
```